# Hyperledger Composer not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install and set up Hyperledger Composer and Playground on Ubuntu 20.04. While executing the following command
curl https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash
I found out, that the website is not reachable or rather existing.
Any ideas? Is there a new website or a new link?

Comment: Hyperledger composer is end of life, all that currently remains is the documentation site, the source code and the published npm modules

Comment: Does that mean I won't be able to curl the image? Bc it is deprecated? @david_k

Comment: Could you recommend an alternative for private Blockchain? Thanks!

Comment: Hyperledger Composer is not a permissioned blockchain. It required Hyperledger Fabric to provide that and was a framework layered on top of hyperledger fabric. So my suggestion would be to look at Hyperledger Fabric